# PHP parse csv list and insert each record into wordpress users database

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got an excel file containing a list of records by firstname, lastname, email_address, transaction_id

I'd like to create a script that reads in the excel data (can be csv or whatever export is easiest to work with) and inserts each record as a user in my wordpress database with the role of "member".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode each line on the delimter (like `,`) or you could use `fopen` and `fgetcsv` to parse line by line. Overall the general procedure is not difficult. for example:

```
$fileResource = fopen('/path/to/file.csv', 'r');
while(($data = fgetcsv($fileResource, ',')) !== false)
{
   // $data is numeric indexed array
   // do stuff with $data
}
```